# Installing Google Chrome in Ubuntu 13.10 Error [How-To]

Tags: software-center, google-chrome, 13.10

Install Google Chrome in Google website, double click the downloaded file, opened up in Ubuntu Software Centre, when I click Install, on the left besides install button it says "only install this file if you trust the origin"

Note: Using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Comment: Yup. there is an Install button, but when i click it, nothing happen.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: This question is not unclear. It's clear as day and quite simple. The .deb file must be executable or software center will prevent installation. Just right click on the .deb and mark it as executable under the permissions tab and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try installing from the command line:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i ./google-chrome*.deb
apt-get install -f
```

Note that this url assumes you are running a 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

google-chrome-stable (32-bit version) depends on lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)

However, ubuntu 13.10 has no lib32gcc1.  It only has libgcc1 or libx32gcc1 or lib64gcc1.

It appears that the 32-bit version of chrome cannot be installed on the 32-bit version of ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

There are dependency problems trying to install Chrome on 13.10, libxss1 .
I suggest contacting Google for support.

In the meantime you can install libxss1 (software centre or from command) and Chrome will install. I did:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

Then Chrome installed fine.

Comment: That didn't do the thing for me. I had it already installed (no idea why) but chrome still won't install. I'm defaulting to chromium until this problem is resolved.

Comment: Silviu, Ubuntu 13.10 64bit ?

Comment: NGRhodes, i might have forgotten that this question is about the 64bit version. I'm running Ubuntu on 32 bit. I tried to install libxss1 but it said it's already installed.

Comment: @Silviu Make it executable before using Software Center.