# Cannot download Google Chrome for Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

Is there something wrong with my setup, because when I try to download the 64-bit .deb from Google the process just gets stuck? The spinner spins, but nothing happens.

Does it work for you?

Comment: How and where are you downloading from?

Comment: I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm located in Finland.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361090/installing-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-13-10-error-how-to), does it help?

Comment: No, because that's about installing the deb. I cannot even download the deb.

Comment: Edit: downloading with wget works.

Comment: glad that it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try with command lines :

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

and then install it :

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

once installed, you can remove the package :

```
rm google-chrome*.deb
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I still wonder why I can't download with Firefox. I don't even have adblock or anything enabled.

Comment: I don't know, I am using `firefox 27.0` and Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, and I can download the .deb both ways (through Firefox and Wget)